# Posting Custom Fields to HTML from Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, shopping-cart

I'm using a free shopping cart template called Roman Cart (https://romancart.com).

Per their documentation, they have the ability to post customer details to the cart (https://www.romancart.com/shopping-cart/how-it-works-examples/#aa).

But unfortunately, me being a newbie, am trying to figure out how and where I should use this? Should I be sending the customer details along with the  tag I use to add items to the shopping cart?

```
    <form action="https://www.romancart.com/cart.asp" method="post"><input type="submit" value="Add to Order"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="670.8">
<input type="hidden" name="storeid" value="10000">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="itemname" value="Pirinho"><br>Include Sample 
<select name="itemname2"required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Select Sample Preference')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" > 
Include sample 
<option value="">-Select-</option>
<option value="Sample Preference: Green {15.00}">Green (+$)</option>
<option value="Sample Preference: Roasted {15.00}">Roasted (+$)</option>
</select><br></form>
```

So to send customer details, should I start using it like this?

```
<input type="hidden" name="CompanyName" value="ACME">
```

Also, I use Wordpress for people to register. How can I get the current_user information and send it alon with the  tag?

```
<input type="hidden" name="CompanyName" value="wp_get_current_user();echo 'Company Name'">
```

I'm pretty sure the above is incorrect and there is a better way to execute this. Can somebody please help me? I will be forever so grateful

Thanks a million!

Comment: I'm seeing that _wp_get_current_user();echo 'Company Name'_ is used without the <?php ?> tags. Are you aware that the functions are not JS but PHP based?

Comment: so should I modify the input tag to read: <input type="hidden" name="CompanyName" value="<?php wp_get_current_user();echo 'Company Name' ?>">

does that even make sense from a syntax stand point?